# How to include my nodejs libraries with Google Cloud Functions

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, shared-libraries

I've just made my first decent Google Cloud Function and now I'd like to refactor it into libraries.

Example, I've got my Cloud Function and I'd like to require a library I've created, not something installed from NPM.

How do I deploy these libraries to Google Cloud Functions?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to create a module out of your `common.js` file.

If that is the case, in `common.js`, export it like so:

```
export default function(){
  // Here is your common code
}
```

and then just import it into your function file:

```
import common from './common.js';
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `--include-node-modules` flag to include `node_modules` folder with deployed sources.

Comment: Hi Gokhan, so if I have a file called common.js which is NOT a node module, how do I include that? The issue is, I don't see my common.js file being deployed when I fire off the gcloud deployment command.

Comment: `--include-node-modules` has been replaced with `--include-ignored-files` See the [updated docs](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/beta/functions/deploy)